# RoR: update action. rendering path when error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, render, edit

Rails project: `Project` has many `Ticket`'s.

Path to editing a ticket: `/projects/12/tickets/11/edit`

When updating a Ticket and validation fails, I use `render :action => "edit"`.

However, when the edit view renders this time, the path changes to `/tickets/11/`

Which means I lose some parameters. How can I keep the original path?

routes.rb:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :tickets
  end
  resources :tickets
```

tickets_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
  end

  def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])
    @ticket.user_id = session[:user_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@ticket.project), :notice => "Ticket was created." }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket])
        format.html { redirect_to project_ticket_path(@ticket.project, @ticket), :notice => "Ticket was updated." }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: can we see your `routes.rb` please?

Answer (score 1):

you are calling resources twice. if you don't want to "lose some parameters", remove the second one.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tickets
end
```

However, if you want to have `resources :tickets` non nested as well, you can restrict it to only `show` and `index` to avoid losing some parameters when creating and editing.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tickets
end
resources :tickets, :only => [:index, :show]
```

**edit** - I believe the problem is in your form than.
Make sure you have both objects:

```
form_for([@project, @ticket]) do |f|
```

Also, you must find the `project` before creating or updating the `ticket`. So your `new` and `edit` actions must have something like:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@ticket = @project.ticket.build
```

and the same for `create` action:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@ticket = @project.ticket.build(params[:ticket])
```

**edit2** - your update action should be something like:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
if @ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket])
...
```

Comment: I've tried that, but this gives me error page when trying to update a ticket: No route matches [PUT] "/tickets/10"

Comment: Ok, I've added  :url => { :action => "update" } in my form_for, in the view. Now it works. However I used the form as a partial view, for create as well. Guess that can't be done?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can use the same form for both (edit and update).

Comment: Excellent, this seem to work fine. I just changed a little bit: form_for [@ticket.project, @ticket] do |f|

Comment: Hmm, now it does not seem to work when you try to update the first time and there's error, the "/edit" in the path is cut off. The second time you try to update the "/project/12/" is cut off as well.

Comment: you must always find the project before dealing with the ticket. The `form_for([@project, @ticket])` in your form will ensure the full url, however you must check that your controller is correct. You can include the tickets_controller in your question, so we can find the problem for you.

Comment: I've tried your code in my controller, but didn't work for me... I've updated the question. I'm collecting the project_id through a hidden_field so I can map it directly to the object.

Comment: I solved it by specifying the action in the form_for with a variable so I could use the view as partial. :url => { :action => @the_action }. Don't know if it's the best solution, but is works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources .
You should be able to redirect to the nested resource from your controller using nested route helpers, such as `project_ticket_path(@project, @ticket)`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to redirect when there's an error, just re-render the view.

Comment: a re-render of the view is the same as a redirect to the show action

Comment: Not really. I'm validating with messages; a redirect will cause a new 302 request, render will not.